# IAuthenticationFilter equivalent in MVC6

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm moving a Web Api 2 project to MVC 6, since Microsoft is merging the two APIs in ASP.NET 5. In my WebApi project I had a custom Attribute Filter class that would authenticate, authorize and prevent transaction replays using a combination of public key, private key and HMAC authentication (basically, [doing this](http://bitoftech.net/2014/12/15/secure-asp-net-web-api-using-api-key-authentication-hmac-authentication/) with some tweaks to fit into my project).

Now in MVC6, as far as I understand I must stop using anything in the Microsoft.Web.Http namespace and instead use Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc. So I have done that, but the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Filters doesn't seem to have any equivalent of Web Api 2's `IAuthenticationFilter`.

This is a problem for me because my customer AuthenticationFilter implemented all of IAuthenticationFilter, with all the logic in there. More importantly, it was using the Context to temporarily store the public key of the account, so my controller could access it to load up the account in turn.

So my question is, what is the proper way to filter requests in MVC6, using an Authentication Filter-like class to intercept the requests and return the appropriate status codes? I can't find any article that goes specifically in these details (they all tend to cover MVC5).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it's an older question, but hopefully someone (maybe even yourself) might find value in the answer.

MVC6 does in fact have an alternative. You have an

```
public abstract class AuthorizationFilterAttribute :
    Attribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter, IAuthorizationFilter, IOrderedFilter
```

which basically tells you, that you can create your custom class, derive it from this (namespace of all of these interfaces, btw, is `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Filters` and that should be it. You can either decorate the action with it, or you can do this in Startup.cs, to apply to *all* actions:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add MVC services to the services container.
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            // add an instance of the filter, like we used to do it
            options.Filters.Add(new MySpecialFilter());
        });

        services.AddTransient<LogFilter>();
    }
```

If you want to use a bit more logic in the filter (e.g. my `LogFilter` above) which is instantiated through DI, you need to use either [Service Filters or Type Filters](http://www.strathweb.com/2015/06/action-filters-service-filters-type-filters-asp-net-5-mvc-6/).

You can now decorate the actions with `[ServiceFilter(typeof(LogFilter))]` or use `o.Filters.Add(new ServiceFilterAttribute(typeof(LogFilter)));` in the Startup.cs file. But keep in mind, to do this you need to **register the type with the DI container**, like I did above with the `.AddTransient<>()` call.

Comment: I'm voting this down because the original question was about authentication filter, and here authorization filter is suggested. Which is different.

Answer (score 0):

IAuthenticationFilter is no more and IAuthorizationFilter simply does not replace it in MVC 6

Reason: authentication is NOT EQUAL to authorization.

Therefore IMO the authentication filter should stay available!